# How can I iterate through two Pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider:

```
In [35]: test = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4),'b':range(4,8)})

In [36]: test
Out[36]:
   a  b
0  0  4
1  1  5
2  2  6
3  3  7

In [37]: for i in test['a']:
   ....:  print i
   ....:
0
1
2
3

In [38]: for i,j in test:
   ....:  print i,j
   ....:
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack


In [39]: for i,j in test[['a','b']]:
   ....:  print i,j
   ....:
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack


In [40]: for i,j in [test['a'],test['b']]:
   ....:  print i,j
   ....:
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use the [DataFrame.itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) method:

```
for a, b in test.itertuples(index=False):
    print a, b
```

Comment: If you have lots of columns and want to iterate on only two of them by name, you can use `zip(test.a, test.b)`. (`zip` in python 3, `from itertools import zip` in python 2.7)

Comment: @drevicko Actually it is `from itertools import izip` in python 2.7

Comment: @drevicko what about for more than 2?

Comment: @makewhite `zip` takes as many iterators as you like, eg. for 3 columns `zip(test.a, test.b, test.c)` will give you tuples `(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 41):

You can use `zip` (this is native in [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3) and can be imported from `itertools` as `izip` in Python 2.7):

### Python 3

```
for a,b in zip(test.a, test.b):
    print(a,b)
```

### Python 2

```
for a,b in izip(test.a, test.b):
    print a,b
```

Answer (score 10):

Try,

```
for i in test.index : print test['a'][i], test['b'][i]
```

to give you,

```
0 4
1 5
2 6
3 7
```

Comment: Someone suggested [a supporting reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loop-or-iterate-over-all-or-certain-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas/), *"Loop or Iterate over all or certain columns of a dataframe in Python-Pandas"*. Could someone review it and consider whether it is legitimate or not? And if it should be included or not?

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the [.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method. It returns the `Index` and `Series` per row:

```
test = DataFrame({'a':range(4),'b':range(4,8)})
for idx, series in test.iterrows():
    print series['a'], series['b']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the contents of two or more rows of a Pandas data frame in a loop, you should consider `iat()`.

Using the variables defined in the question:

```py
for ind in range(df.shape[0]):
    print(test.iat[ind, 0], test.iat[ind, 1])
```

`iat()` allows the data frame to be accessed as a conventional 2D matrix.